# Is there a different name for these two types of subordinate clauses?

Tags: clauses, relative-clauses, subordinate-clauses

> The book *that you bought me* fell off the table.

And

> The book *that contains the recipes* fell off the table.

Note that the first has a subject and the second one doesn't.

Warriner's *Grammar of English* states that these are adjective clauses, but doesn't note anything on the issue of subject.

Comment: No. They are both called "relative clauses" (but "adjective clauses" is also accurate, since like adjectives, they modify nouns).

Answer (score 1):

Both sentences use *that* as a relative pronoun. The relative clauses in both sentences are defining or restrictive, hence modifying rather than parenthetical.  The [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/relative-pronouns) website comments:

> We use that instead of who, whom or which in relative clauses to refer
>   to people, animals and things. We use it to introduce defining clauses
>   only. That is more informal than who, whom or which...

The same entry proceeds to explain that *that* can serve as either the subject of object of a relative clause:

> *That* can act as the subject or the object of the relative clause:
>
> *He finally remembers one lesson that his mum had taught him early –
>   Don’t take money that doesn’t belong to you.* (*that* refers to money and
>   is the subject of *belong* in the relative clause)
>
> *It’s the same cooker that my mother has.* (*that* refers to the same
>   cooker and is the object of *has* in the relative clause)

The relative clauses in both of your example sentences are complete and well formed. The primary difference is in the role played by the relative pronoun, *that*.  In the first sentence, the relative pronoun is, itself, the subject of the relative clause; in the second one, the relative pronoun is the direct object of the relative clause.